# How to send Post request in image url parameters (in Get request)

Tags: image, http, url, post, get

Is it possible to send a Post request in image url parameters (in Get request)?

I know, I shouldn't want that.
I can't use JavaScript or forms. Just img tag and need to make post request instead of get request.

Is what possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer is No.

An `<img />` tag will result in a `GET` request, im not aware of anyway of changing that behaviour.

I think all solutions would have to revolve around either using JavaScript to make a POST request in background then manipulating the `<img/>` tag, or using a server side script to act as a proxy making a `POST` on your behalf.